# Parentheses or quotations for English name (foreigner)?

Tags: business-language, email, parentheses, quotation-marks, nicknames

My English name is Michael (my name is Minh, so Michael and Minh have some similarity).

Should I put my name as: Minh "Michael" Nguyen or Minh (Michael) Nguyen (on a résumé, business card, email signature, etc.)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP's preferred name, not the use of English

Comment: In my experience, it's typical to put your American name first, as that's the name you go by, and are inviting others to call you; thus, most cards I see "Michael (Minh) Nguyen".

Answer (score 4):

It is appropriate to include one's preferred name on a résumé or other business correspondence. See [this page](http://www.theladders.com/career-advice/when-use-nicknames-legal-names). Many English speakers would have no idea how to pronounce "Minh" (or "Nguyen").

I would prefer Minh (Michael) Nguyen. This clearly tells me, a native English speaker, that I should address you as "Michael". If I have never met you, I appreciate knowing that I can call you "Michael", and I don't have to awkwardly mispronounce your name or ask you for your name.

I would not use Minh "Michael" Nguyen. Informal nicknames are enclosed in quotes, and are not usually appropriate for a business context.

If you will be conducting all your business in English, and will infrequently do business with someone who speaks your native language, you may want to simply use Michael Nguyen. Business associates and contacts probably won't care what your native name is, and your employer will understand that your legal name is different from your social name.

On a deeper level, you may want to display your native name to show that you value your native culture or background. Or, you may want to leave out your native name to more fully embrace the English-speaking culture you are in.

EDIT:

As Dan Bron said, Michael (Minh) Nguyen is also common and acceptable.

Comment: I like this answer, especially for the use of "English" to refer to the language of the name, rather than saying "American name".  The OP's Vietnamese name is as fully American as any English name.